# How can I make use of cong and injective with indexed vectors in Idris?

Tags: vector, idris, theorem-proving

`cong` and `injective` allow you to apply and unapply functions to equalities:

```
cong : (f : a -> b) -> x = y -> f x = f y

injective : Injective f => f x = f y -> x = y
```

Both of these fail for indexed vectors with different lengths, for obvious reasons.

How can I prove that two equal vectors have the same length? I.e.

```
sameLen : {xs : Vect n a} -> {ys : Vect m b} -> xs = ys -> n = m
```

I can't just do

```
sameLen pf = cong length pf
```

because `length` on `xs` has type `Vect n a -> Nat` and `length` on `ys` has type `Vect m b -> Nat`. (In fact, I'm not even sure how to prove the same thing for two regular `List`s, due to the differing type arguments, never mind with the added indices).

Going the other way, how would I prove something like

```
data Rose a = V a | T (Vect n (Rose a))
Injective T where
    injective Refl = Refl
unwrap : {xs : Vect n (Rose a)} -> {ys : Vect m (Rose b)} -> T xs = T ys -> xs = ys
```

Again, I can't just do

```
unwrap pf = injective pf
```

due to the differing types of `T` (one with m and one with n). And even if I had a proof `m=n`, how could I use that to convince Idris that the two applications of `T` are the same?

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer from the Idris Discord - if you pattern match on `Refl` then it unifies `a` and `b` automatically:

```
sameLen : {xs : List a} -> {ys : List b} -> xs = ys -> length xs = length ys
sameLen Refl = Refl

sameLen' : {xs : Vect n a} -> {ys : Vect m b} -> xs = ys -> n = m
sameLen' Refl = Refl
```